# How can I display several markers at one point

Tags: google-maps

I'm developing add-on using the `google maps js api v3` for a real estate agency homepage.

In this case, in the map, I'm determining the marker's position using the zipcode and the city.  So, sometimes there are more than one marker at the some place.

So, my problem is how can I display several markers at one point?

Comment: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html

Comment: https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of problem and I found a plugin to deal with that : [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet)

Let me know if solve your issue.

@DrMolle: The MarkerClusterer plugin might not work if the markers are on the exact same location

Comment: Please add the comment on the correct thread (Question comments)